# Keep Bootstrap tooltip open by default

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Is it possible to keep Twitter Bootstrap tooltip open by default and instead hide it on an event? If so, please let me know how.

Answer (score 1):

This may help somebody. In bootstrap 4 you can always show the tooltip with the following code:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show')
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar work done on this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm8Lr/1/ would this be an option?

Will carry on working on

Consider something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $(".show-tooltip").on("mouseover", function(){

        $(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip('show');

    }); 


    $(".hide-tooltip").click(function(){

        $(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip('hide');

    }); 

});

</script>
```